# Is session really needed in tensorflow2?

Tags: tensorflow, session

I'm so confused why it remains keeping the session in tf2 as said by the official eager mode has so many beneficial. Also sometimes I'm not sure whether to use session or not, and keep making bugs in tf programming, sometimes adding session just trying luck.

Comment: It's just there for compatibility reasons with TF1 code. IMHO they should have removed it completely; I would recommend that you just never use it (can't think of a good reason to use it).

Comment: @xdurch0 I totally agree with you. I have just encountered a problem that should not happen on tf1 but in tf2. I have built the model eagerly, and want to check if my model is built correctly. So I added some code as instructions in https://tensorflow.google.cn/tensorboard/graphs?hl=en. However, as the issues in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1961. It cannot export the profiling due to the eager mode, so how should I check my model, is there any other tools?

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow 2 does not require session.

Every v1.Session.run call should be replaced by a Python function.

- The feed_dict and v1.placeholders become function arguments.
- The fetches become the function's return value.
- During conversion eager execution allows easy debugging with standard Python tools like pdb.

For more details take a look at [Tensorflow migration guideline](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#1_replace_v1sessionrun_calls).